# BATCH file showing error

Tags: batch-file

My batch file keeps showing an error but it flashes to quick for me to read it. Any help?(im new to batch so don't make to much fun of me haha)

```
title A Path Unknown
 @Echo off
:Begining
echo Welcome to Path Unknown
set /p USERNAME=Whats your name?
echo Hello %USERNAME% , Listen I know we just met but I really need your help, please follow me.
 set /p FOLLOW=Type Y to follow her and X to say "NO WAY!"
 if Y = true goto :Home
 if X = true goto :Begining
 :Home
```

Comment: Run your batch file from a command prompt (i.e. `cmd`), then you'll be able to see the error.

Comment: I do run it using cmd. it flashes the error so quickly I cant read it

Comment: There's nothing in your script which clears the screen, so I don't see why you wouldn't be able to see the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help man. when u said cmd I thought u meant clicking on the folder I saved it which opens it through cmd then when done closes it quickly. but by typing it all at once in literal cmd it showed the error. Thanks again, you were a huge help!

Comment: When you answered "I do run it using cmd", although you really run it via a double-click from the explorer, you just rejected the efforts of the people trying to help you. If you don't understand an advice given to you, ask for a clarification instead of give inaccurate details; otherwise it will be very difficult to try to aid you in future questions... **`:(`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your `if` statements are incorrect. You should be comparing the value of `FOLLOW` to `Y` or `N`, like this:

```
if "%FOLLOW%" == "Y" goto :Home
if "%FOLLOW%" == "N" goto :Begining
```

Note that since `:Home` is at the bottom of the script, you don't really need the `goto :Home` condition, as the flow will naturally end here anyway.

Comment: Dude your a livesaver man. Worked like a charm. Thanks so much I would upvote you if I had the 15 rep

Comment: No worries! I think you can still upvote answers to your own questions, but if you can't, you can still select my answer as the "accepted answer".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the pause command at the end of your script